# CSS flexbox (flex-grow / flex-basis) - Same width, but doesn't wrap anymore

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use flexboxes to organize elements on my page.

I want the flexboxes to use all available horizontal space, so I add `flex-grow:1`.

Then I want each item on the same line to be of the same size (e.g. 50% each if there is two items, 33% if there is three, etc), so I add `flex-basis:0`.

But at the third step, the items don't wrap anymore. If I change the window width, the number of items per line stays always the same, and their content is squeezed. I don't want that. I want an item to be put on the next line when their width become smaller than it's content, as it works in the first two steps. I tried playing with `flex-shrink` and other things, without success.

What can I do ? Thanks !

**Answer TL;DR:** Adding `min-width: fit-content` works !

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6kgmkn6/)

Answer (score 3):

Although you have `flex-wrap` set to `wrap`, there is no `width` defined for the flex items (`li`), and you have `flex-basis` set to 0. This means that the initial main size of the flex items is 0. It won't wrap because it can shrink to zero (even if the `flex-shrink` property is 0).

#### Solution #1

One thing you can do is set the `flex-basis` property to `content` or `auto`.

```
li { flex-basis: auto; }
```

This tells the flex item to factor in the width of its content.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s6kgmkn6/3/)

> [**`flex-basis`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis)
>
> The initial main size of the flex item.
>
> ***`auto`***
>
> When specified on a flex item, the `auto` keyword retrieves the value
>   of the main size property as the used `flex-basis`. If that value is
>   also `auto`, then the used value is `content`.
>
> ***`content`***
>
> Indicates automatic sizing, based on the flex item’s content.
>
> *Note: Note that `content` was not present in the initial release of
>   Flexible Box Layout, and thus some older implementations will not
>   support it. The equivalent effect can be had by using `auto` together
>   with a main size (width or height) of `auto`.*

This diagram from the [flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-basis) *tries* to explain the difference between `flex-basis: 0` and `flex-basis: auto`. [Here's a more complete explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)

[image]

---

#### Solution #2

Another method to vertically stack flex items on smaller screens is to change the [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) in a media query:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 500px ) {
    ul { flex-direction: column; }
    li { flex-basis: auto; }
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s6kgmkn6/4/)

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer.
However with solution #1, items on the same line doesn't have the same width anymore (I have to left `flex-basis` at 0 for that).
Solution 2 may work, but removes one of the interests of using flexboxes, which is to adapt automatically both with items and screen width (no "hard numbers" in pixels).

Comment: The 500px in media query is just for demo. You can use relative units and `calc`, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would use media queries to change the `flex-direction` of the element to `column` if the items are too big for the window width. This will put the items of a list below each other.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="grid__row grid__row--sm">
    <li>1 small</li>
    <li>1 wide wide wide wide wide wide</li>
</ul>
<ul class="grid__row grid__row--sm">
    <li>2 medium medium</li>
    <li>2 small</li>
</ul>
<ul class="grid__row grid__row--md">
    <li>3 small</li>
    <li>3 wide wide wide wide wide wide</li>
    <li>3 medium medium</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid__row {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.grid__row li {
    background: green;
    color: white;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 15px;
    display:flex;
    flex: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .grid__row--sm {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .grid__row--md {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6kgmkn6/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't set flex-basis to `auto` or `content` because you want all boxes to be the same size, so `flex-basis` has to be `0` and `flex-grow` set to `1`, as you've correctly done. What you need to do now is set `min-width` (e.g. `200px`) on the flex items. Your mileage may vary, I believe safari (webkit has been doing a terribly job of keeping up since google went to blink) may be buggy with `min-width` on `flex-items`.

Alternatively you could just set the flex-basis to be the `min-width` property which should work, even in safari (`flex: 1 0 200px`)

```css
ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
    background: green;
    margin: 1px;
    flex: 1 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1 small</li>
    <li>1 wide wide wide wide wide wide</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>2 medium medium</li>
    <li>2 small</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>3 small</li>
    <li>3 wide wide wide wide wide wide</li>
    <li>3 medium medium</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not want to put "hard numbers" in pixels in the code, because one of the interest of using flexboxes is to adapt automatically both with items and screen width. However the answer was in `min-width` as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Michael_B and Adam, I have found the solution to my problem.

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
min-width: fit-content;
```

The `fit-content` value of `min-width` is the key here. It is experimental (you may have to add a browser prefix), but it does exactly what I wanted: same width, with wrap !